# custom field set with multiple years of data

Tags: wordpress, civimember, custom-fields

We are on WordPress4.3.1, civi 4.4.1.

I want to be able to track multiple years of data related to a group of our contacts.  Would I set this up within custom fields, with date being one of the fields?

I will need to produce reports with the history.  The documentation says that I won't be able search for these fields.

Is there a way that I can do this from within civi? Thanks